# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)when trying to access goodread api

Tags: python, json, flask

```
@app.route("/review/", methods=["POST", "GET"])

def review(isbn):
    uid = session["user"].id

    if request.method == "GET":

        data = db.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn=:isbn ", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchall()

        rating = db.execute("SELECT * FROM review join book ON review.bid = book.id join users On review.uid = users.id WHERE isbn =:isbn ", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchall()

        res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "LZdw0fSUvZVtB5Gprc6DQ", "isbns": bnum})

        bookinfo = res.json()

        avr = bookinfo['books'][0]['average_rating']

        rvr = bookinfo['books'][0]['work_ratings_count']

        return render_template("review.html",
                               data=data, rating=rating, avr=avr, rvr=rvr)
```

...
hello guys when I am running the code to access book rating and rating count from goodreads api this error appears. but when I use an isbn number instead isbn variable it works.
note: isbn is passed from html page...\I want to pass isbn value through url

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable passed in the app.route as a parameter
You are directly using it in the function below it, you will need to do the following to use in flask.
I am assuming the isbn number is an integer

```
@app.route("/review/<int:isbn>", methods=["POST", "GET"])    # You need to pass the isbn in your app.route like this

def review(isbn):
    uid = session["user"].id

    if request.method == "GET":

        data = db.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE isbn=:isbn ", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchall()

        rating = db.execute("SELECT * FROM review join book ON review.bid = book.id join users On review.uid = users.id WHERE isbn =:isbn ", {"isbn": isbn}).fetchall()

        res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "LZdw0fSUvZVtB5Gprc6DQ", "isbns": bnum})

        bookinfo = res.json()

        avr = bookinfo['books'][0]['average_rating']

        rvr = bookinfo['books'][0]['work_ratings_count']

        return render_template("review.html",
                               data=data, rating=rating, avr=avr, rvr=rvr)
```

Comment: isbn is pass from html page to this route and in the url parameter I called isbn but it didn't work.

Comment: I changed the bnum to isbn